# bash shell nested for loop

Tags: bash, shell, nested-loops

I want to write a nested for loop that has to work in the bash shell prompt. nested for loop in Single line command.

For example,

```
for i in a b; do echo $i; done
a
b
```

In the above example, for loop is executed in a single line command right.
Like this I have tried the nested for loop in the shell prompt. Its not working. 
How to do this. Please update me on this.

Comment: -bash-3.00# for i in a b; do echo $i; done <next-line>a <next-line>b <next-line>-bash-3.00#

Comment: in the above comments i have mentioned <next-line> to represend the new line... command is "for i in a b; do echo $i; done"

Comment: Please EDIT your question, do not add this kind of comments. I edited to highlight the code...

Comment: Saying "it's not working" conveys no information. How does the behavior differ from what you expect? What error messages are you getting? What have you tried?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The question does not contain a nested loop, just a single loop. But THIS nested version works, too:

```
# for i in c d; do for j in a b; do echo $i $j; done; done
c a
c b
d a
d b
```

Answer (score 69):

On one line (semi-colons necessary):

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do echo "$i$j"; done; done
```

Formatted for legibility (no semi-colons needed):

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
    for j in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    do 
        echo "$i$j"
    done
done
```

There are different views on how the shell code should be laid out over multiple lines; that's about what I normally use, unless I put the next operation on the same line as the `do` (saving two lines here).

Comment: Why not do something like for i in $(seq 0 9) instead of writing out each number in the sequence?

Comment: @SummerEla: You could `$(seq 0 9)`; in Bash, you could write `for i in {0..9}` too.  There are lots of ways that could be used.  The advantage of not using `seq` is that it saves on processes (11 of them).  You're unlikely to find that's a problem, but it is a nominal reason for using one of the alternative notations (the one in the answer, or the brace expansion).  Note that brace expansion is not very flexible - and neither is the written out list of numbers.  The `seq` notation allows you to control the range with variable limits.  It all depends on what you're after.

Answer (score 13):

```
#!/bin/bash
# loop*figures.bash

for i in 1 2 3 4 5  # First loop.
do
    for j in $(seq 1 $i)
    do
        echo  -n "*" 
    done
    echo 
done
echo
# outputs
# *
# **
# ***
# ****
# *****

for i in 5 4 3 2 1 # First loop.
do
    for j in $(seq -$i -1)
    do
        echo  -n "*" 
    done
    echo 
done

# outputs
# *****
# ****
# ***
# **
# *

for i in 1 2 3 4 5  # First loop.
do
    for k in $(seq -5 -$i)
    do
        echo -n ' '
    done
    for j in $(seq 1 $i)
    do
        echo  -n "* " 
    done
    echo 
done
echo

# outputs
#     * 
#    * * 
#   * * * 
#  * * * * 
# * * * * * 

for i in 1 2 3 4 5  # First loop.
do
    for j in $(seq -5 -$i)
    do
        echo  -n "* " 
    done
    echo 
    for k in $(seq 1 $i)
    do
        echo -n ' '
    done
done
echo

# outputs
# * * * * * 
#  * * * * 
#   * * * 
#    * * 
#     *


exit 0
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation in addition to the code.

Comment: You are a savior  :)