# How to use for loop with multiple variables in linux

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, for-loop

I have a command I need to run for multiple combinations of files. The command looks like this:

```
myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_"$TARGET_SAMPLE"_vs_"$NORMAL_SAMPLE" -target_sample /path/$TARGET_SAMPLE.bam -normal_sample /path/$NORMAL_SAMPLE.bam
```

I want to run this for multiple sets of samples without having to manually change the paths each time. Right now I set the samples before running it mannually like this:

```
export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_1"
export NORMAL_SAMPLE="sample_2"
```

How do I run this to make sure the TARGET_SAMPLE and NORMAL_SAMPLE are always correctly matched? For each NORMAL_SAMPLE I need to run the script twice with two different TARGET_SAMPLE files. I think using an array could work but I don't know how to correctly feed that into a for loop.

Here are a few examples of the pairings I need to run:

```
export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_1"
export NORMAL_SAMPLE="sample_2"

export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_3"
export NORMAL_SAMPLE="sample_2"

export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_4"
export NORMAL_SAMPLE="sample_5"

export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_6"
export NORMAL_SAMPLE="sample_5"
```

So the first example outputs from this list of combinations would be to submit these commands in the shell:

```
myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_sample_1_vs_sample_2 -target_sample /path/sample_1.bam -normal_sample /path/sample_2.bam
```

and the second would be:

```
myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_sample_3_vs_sample_2 -target_sample /path/sample_3.bam -normal_sample /path/sample_2.bam
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use a couple of arrays (namely target and normal) with the pairs occupying the same positions in both arrays.

Comment: so would that involve two for loops cycling through each array?

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong with your code because you did not provide it or the errors you encountered. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Possible duplicate of [bash shell nested for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4847854/608639)

Comment: I don't have any errors for this because I don't know how to create a for loop that pairs specific variables together rather than just looping through a single set of variables or all possible combinations. I don't see it as a straightforward nested loop because I have a hardcoded list of possible combinations of TARGET_SAMPLE and NORMAL_SAMPLE that should be run together.

Comment: No, only a single loop. Say `normal=(n1 n3 n3)` and `target=(t2 t3 t4)`. Both arrays have three elements. As long as you keep the ordering you are interested into, you can loop with a variable `n` from 0 to length(normal) and using `${normal[n]}` and `${target[n]}` as your parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1 using while-loop reading multiple values from a "here-document":

```
export TARGET_SAMPLE NORMAL_SAMPLE

# special characters in the values (eg. space) will cause problems
while read TARGET_SAMPLE NORMAL_SAMPLE ANYTHING_ELSE; do
    # insert sanity checks here
    myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_"$TARGET_SAMPLE"_vs_"$NORMAL_SAMPLE" -target_sample /path/$TARGET_SAMPLE.bam -normal_sample /path/$NORMAL_SAMPLE.bam
done <<'EOD'
sample_1 sample_2
sample_3 sample_2
sample_4 sample_5
sample_6 sample_5
EOD
```

Method 1b as Method 1 but read data from an external file:

```
# spcial characters in the values (eg. space) will cause problems
cat >mydata <<'EOD'
sample_1 sample_2
sample_3 sample_2
sample_4 sample_5
sample_6 sample_5
EOD

export TARGET_SAMPLE NORMAL_SAMPLE

# normally $ANYTHING_ELSE should be empty but embedded spaces will confuse read
cat mydata | while read TARGET_SAMPLE NORMAL_SAMPLE ANYTHING_ELSE; do
    # insert sanity checks here
    myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_"$TARGET_SAMPLE"_vs_"$NORMAL_SAMPLE" -target_sample /path/$TARGET_SAMPLE.bam -normal_sample /path/$NORMAL_SAMPLE.bam
done
```

Method 2 wrapping with a shell function:

```
export TARGET_SAMPLE NORMAL_SAMPLE

wrapper(){
    TARGET_SAMPLE=$1
    NORMAL_SAMPLE=$2
    # insert sanity checks here
    myscript.pl -output_directory /path/output_"$TARGET_SAMPLE"_vs_"$NORMAL_SAMPLE" -target_sample /path/$TARGET_SAMPLE.bam -normal_sample /path/$NORMAL_SAMPLE.bam
}

wrapper "sample_1" "sample_2"
wrapper "sample_3" "sample_2"
wrapper "sample_4" "sample_5"
wrapper "sample_6" "sample_5"
```

Method 3 using for loop over multiple arrays:

Bash has indexed array variables so a for loop is possible but keeping the arrays synchronised is error-prone so I don't recommend it.

Comment: `cat file | while read ...` is better written `while read; do ... done < file`

Comment: Method 1 works great however sometimes I have to submit the command to a LSF using bsub and if I don't export the variable with export TARGET_SAMPLE="sample_1" it doesn't work, is there a way to export the variables using Method 1? Apologies if that is not very clear.

Comment: Point taken. The cat is intended as a placeholder. It could have been something more complicated like the output of grep or a database query or a longer pipeline.